# How could I set multi redirect_uri for the same client_id in abp frameworks 7.x

Tags: c#, abp, openiddict

Can I set multi redirect_uri for the same client_id like other oauth serber ？
for example, keycloack and google can set multi valid redirect URIs in one client_id.

I have no ideal how to do it.
I try set data to database table OpenIddictApplications, but it no work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. At least when using the EFCore storage, `OpenIddictApplications.RedirectUris` (and `PostLogoutRedirectUris`) contains a JSON string array, so you can allow multiple `redirect_uri`s for the same `client_id` by setting the value in the database to an array with multiple values. For example:

```json
["https://instance1.example.org/oidc-login", "https://instance2.example.com/login/oidc/callback"]
```